# Unzip list into several combinations

Tags: python, list-comprehension, unzip

Let's see if I can explain what I am looking for. I want unwrap a list according to those elements which are a list in a list (tweaky, I know!).

I want this:

```
a = [[1],[2],[5],[4,6],[3]]
```

to be transform to this:

```
b = [[[1],[2],[5],[4],[3]],[[1],[2],[5],[6],[3]]]
```

And also applied to:

```
a = [[1],[2,3],[5],[4,6],[3]]
```

for achieving:

```
b = [[[1],[2],[5],[4],[3]],[[1],[2],[5],[6],[3]],[[1],[3],[5],[4],[3]],[[1],[3],[5],[6],[3]]]
```

I hope I have expressed propertly. I have been looking for some buil-in function that performs this operation but I have find nothing.

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Does your last `list` sample have any extra data tacked on?  To clarify, the last `list` is larger than the previous `a` and `b` lists combined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [[1],[2,3],[5],[4,6],[3]]
>>> for tup in itertools.product(*a):
...     print tup
...
(1, 2, 5, 4, 3)
(1, 2, 5, 6, 3)
(1, 3, 5, 4, 3)
(1, 3, 5, 6, 3)
```

You can convert the tuples to lists and wrap the elements in 1-element lists if you really want to.

Comment: What's the significance of `a = a = [[1],[2,3],[5],[4,6],[3]]`, why not `a = [[1],[2,3],[5],[4,6],[3]]` ?

Comment: @Raiyan: I think I accidentally both typed the `a =` part and copy-pasted it from the line in the question. It's fixed now.